# CSS Text-Transform Selector

Tags: html, css

This is my code

```
<li class="nav-item">
        <a href="" class="nav-link" id="welcome">Welcome, {{request.user}}</a>
    </li>
```

Is there a way of selecting the first letter of the user's name and capitalizing it with just CSS?
Is it possible to do this in a way similar to selecting the first-letter and using the text-transform command?

Thank you in advance for any help. I'm new to web design and trying to avoid Javascript until I'm comfortable with CSS.

Comment: have you try using `text-transform: capitalize` ?

Answer (score 1):

No. You can do [**`:first-letter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter) but it has to be the **actual** first letter.

> The ::first-letter CSS pseudo-element applies styles to the first letter of the first line of a block-level element, but only when not preceded by other content (such as images or inline tables).

So wrap the username in a `span` and try this:

```css
a {
 text-decoration:none;
  color:grey;
}

ul {
  list-style:none;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
}

a span:first-letter {
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul><li class="nav-item">
        <a href="" class="nav-link" id="welcome">Welcome, <span>username</span></a>
    </li></ul>
```